# react update component margin-top with jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Splash extends React.Component {
    updateVideoMarginTop() {
        // update #video-wrapper height() to match window.height
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="video-wrapper">
                <video id="video">
                    <source id="mp4" src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
            </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default Splash;
```

What is the best way (less jQuery and more react if possible) of updating the margin-top of a component to match the window height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use inline styles for example like so:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Splash extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="video-wrapper" style={{ marginTop: `${window.innerHeight}px` }}>
        <video id="video">
          <source id="mp4" src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>  
    );
  } 
}

export default Splash;
```

Notice the `style` attribute on the outer div. You can apply inline styles to any element. Just keep in mind, the css you apply is written in camelCase, for example `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`, and all values have to be in quotes (unlike real css).